# Get userData from xml

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I want to extact   lines from my xml. Here is an example:

```
<userData code="viPartListRailML" value="1">
            <partRailML s="0.0000000000000000e+00" id="0"/>
            <partRailML s="2.0000000000000000e+01" id="1"/>
            <partRailML s="9.4137883373059267e+01" id="2"/>
        </userData>
        <userData code="viBaliseList" value="1">
        </userData>
        <userData code="viAxleCounterList" value="1">
        </userData>
```

I was trying this code, but it doesnt give back value:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

mydoc = minidom.parse('N:\SAJAT_MAPPAK\IGYULAVICS\/adhoc\pythonXMLread\probaxml\github_minta.xml')
items = mydoc.getElementsByTagName('userData')
# all items data
print('\nAll item data:')
for elem in items:
    print(elem.firstChild.data)
```

And the expected result would be like:

```
<userData code="viPartListRailML" value="1"><partRailML s="0.0000000000000000e+00" id="0"/><partRailML s="2.0000000000000000e+01" id="1"/><partRailML s="9.4137883373059267e+01" id="2"/></userData>
```

Can you help me, to find my mistake?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: you need to get entire rows with tags from xml file?

Comment: yes, I need it like that

Comment: selection of `userData` is done based on what? `viPartListRailML`?